# Computing limit of sinx/x as x approaches infinity

Tags: limits

I looked at the solution of sin(2x)/x as x approaches infinity (https://www.mathway.com/popular-problems/Calculus/569134).

1. I understand -1 <= sin(2x)<=1. Now, my issue is when he multiply the inequality by 1/x. What if x is negative, then you have to reverse  the inequality?
2. Also, if you use the L'hopital rule instead of squeeze theorem for sin(2x)/x you get it is equal to limit of 2sin(2x)/1. 2sin(2x)/1 as x goes to infinity is undefind ! So squeeze theorem says the original limit is 0 while the L Hoptial rule says the original limit is undefined. Which rule do you use?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your conclusion in (2) is wrong: L'Hopital's rule does not say anything if the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest use of the squeeze theorem for $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{\sin f(x)}{x}$ is $-\frac{1}{|x|}\le\frac{\sin f(x)}{x}\le\frac{1}{|x|}$, so the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are taking $x \to \infty$ you don't have to worry about the case where $x$ is negative.
2. You cannot apply l'Hopital's rule because the numerator $\sin(2x)$ does not have a limit as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Actually you *can* apply l'Hopital's rule to $f(x)/g(x)$ if only the denominator diverges to infinity – as long as the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists.